# Why should I use both MyDB and MyDBhelper (Android, SQLite)?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have searched online and have looked at some books for Android code and found some contradicting information.

In The Android Developer's Cookbook, the authors describe three classes: MyDB.java, MyDBhelper.java, and Constants.java.

- MyDB.java is used to open and close the DB as well as insert and query the DB (I'd assume they would also put update, row deletion, etc in this class as well).
- MyDBhelper.java (extends SQLiteHelper) is used for the onCreate() and onUpdate() methods. The DB's tables are created in onCreate().
- Constants.java is used to define constants used by both MyDB.java and MyDBhelper.java.

Online, I found a few examples (I can link them if needed) that simply do not use the MyDB.java concept. These examples include everything in the MyDBhelper.java class.

Is one way better than the other? Is there a reason to keep the onCreate and onUpdate methods in a separate class from the data manipulation/querying class? I understand that both can work, but I'm looking for the more widely accepted approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the general concept is that you want to separate your UI logic from the database logic, and the MyDB class interfaces between the particulars of the DB and your UI.

Your UI would want to treat the data as Java constructs (like collections, strings, and such).  The MyDBhelper does all of the actual IO, reading the data from the DB into Cursors.  The MyDB class acts as a go-between, converting the Cursor data into regular Java constructs.

An example:

In the Activity:

```
ArrayList(Customer> ac = MyDBhelper.getCustomers();
```

In MyDB:

```
Cursor c = MyDBhelper.getCustomers();
ArrayList<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<Customer>();
// For each row in the returned Cursor, create a Customer object, and add it to an ArrayList<Customer> collection.
// return the ArrayList to the UI
return customers;
```

MyDBhelper does the job of creating the needed SQLite query string to get the data it needs, and calls the SQLite database
to read the data into a Cursor.  It returns the Cursor to MyDB.

Comment: The logic between MyDB and MyDBhelper makes a lot of sense. But, using that logic, why would you put the queries into MyDBhelper if the queries are generated by UI events?

Comment: It's all about design, OOP, MVC, and encapsulation.  What if you want to use another database?  What of you want to use the same database in a Windows or Linux program?  If the database code is in the UI, you have to change it if the database changes.